# Registration email link not being sent

Tags: users, form, emails, post

I'm using the following form, and occasionally through testing the e-mail activation link will send, however the majority of time it never gets sent. Did I do something wrong with the form?

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/success/">

        {% macro errorList(errors) %}
            {% if errors %}
                <ul class="errors">
                    {% for error in errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endmacro %}

        {% from _self import errorList %}

        <h3><label for="username">Username</label></h3>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username"
            {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%}>

        {% if account is defined %}
            {{ errorList(account.getErrors('username')) }}
        {% endif %}

        <h3><label for="email">Email</label></h3>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email"
            {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %}>

        {% if account is defined %}
            {{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
        {% endif %}

        <h3><label for="password">Password</label></h3>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password">

        {% if account is defined %}
            {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
        {% endif %}

        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

Comment: The form looks fine. If you turn on debug mode and look at your craft.log you should be able to see if craft attempted to send an email or not, or if there was an error. Might also check that they're not getting spam filtered. The `'testToEmailAddress'` in your config file is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `phpmail` or `sendmail` under Settings->Email in the control panel, they are notoriously unreliable at delivering emails consistently.

Try using a proper SMTP relay or a transactional email provider like [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/).

Comment: Recently I discovered mailjet. 6000 mails per moth for free.